# Git commit shows over 100 commits after merge

Tags: git

When I merged my branch `A` to branch `B` and was ready to commit and push, my console told me that there were `101 commits` that I will be pushing. Question is, how can I remove all these commits into just one commit so that my branch `B` history doesn't get flooded with unnecessary branch `A` 101 commit history.

Comment: That's call "git squash". Search with this term and you get many tutorials.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hmm it looks like 'qit squash` use used with `git rebase` instead of git merge. I am familiar with `git rebase` and was going to use it moving forward for my merges however, is the same 'git squash` aviabale for `git merge`?

Answer (score 1):

You can `sqash` the commits of the branch `A`.

It can be done by using `rebase`.

> $ git rebase -i HEAD~100 // For doing operation on latest 100 commits

This command will open a file having following details

> pick #first_commit_hash# #first_commit_message#
>
> pick #second_commit_hash# #second_commit_meesage#
>
> ... and so on

Change `pick` to `squash` for the commits to which you want to merge into the previous commit. `squash` will append the commit message of the squashed commit into its previous commit. If you want to discard the commit message use `fixup`. You can find all the option in the file opened when you run rebase command.

If you replace `pick` with `squash` for the 99 commits, at the end of rebase you will have 1 single commit which contains changes of all the 100 commits. Then you can merge this single commit in the branch `B`.